# Nuget restore package not working after reinstall VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild-4.0, nuget-package-restore

This is error I am getting when I am trying to build project.
and one more thing I have noticed that it throws error on Exec command.

here is the build output.

1>Target "_DownloadNuGet" in project "D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits.nuget\nuget.targets" (entry point):
1>Task "DownloadNuGet" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(DownloadNuGetExe)' == 'true' AND !Exists('$(NuGetExePath)')) was evaluated as ( 'false' == 'true' AND !Exists('D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits.nuget\NuGet.exe')).
1>Done building target "_DownloadNuGet" in project "nuget.targets".
1>Done executing task "MsBuild".
1>Done building target "CheckPrerequisites" in project "Benefits.CustomerCore.csproj".
1>Target "RestorePackages" in file "D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits.nuget\nuget.targets" from project "D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits\Benefits.CustomerCore\Benefits.CustomerCore.csproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
1>Task "Exec" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' And Exists('$(PackagesConfig)')) was evaluated as ('Windows_NT' != 'Windows_NT' And Exists('D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits\Benefits.CustomerCore\packages.config')).
1>Using "Exec" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "Exec"
1>  "D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits\Benefits.CustomerCore\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits\ "
1>D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits.nuget\nuget.targets(92,9): error : The system cannot find the path specified.
1>  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
1>D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits.nuget\nuget.targets(92,9): error MSB3073: The command ""D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits\Benefits.CustomerCore\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\Projects\TCG\branches\BenefitsPlus-14.5.20\Customisation\Benefits\ "" exited with code -1.
1>Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "RestorePackages" in project "Benefits.CustomerCore.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>

Comment: I highly recommend that you stop using the Nuget.targets approach and use the new [automatic restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore). It is not a proper "solution" to your problem, but I suspect it will start working. You will need to update nuget (if it is not updated already) and remove a few lines of your csproj files.

Comment: Do you have multiple solutions in different folders, referencing the same projects? This problem seems to be related to the solution path variable that is stored in each csproj file when you enable package restore (as I pointed out in the previous comment, this package restore mechanism you are using is deprecated). Can you check that the `<SolutionDir>` in the csproj (open the project as a xml file and use search) is correctly pointing to the solution folder and that the solution folder has a corresponding `packages` folder?